# Google Sheets - Conditional Formatting on Closest Value

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a column of data and a target value and am wanting to apply a rule that will highlight the closest value to that target value from the column of data possible. I have tried a few different forumla and nothing has worked so far. This is what I am currently working with:

Target Number is in I3
Data is in I4:I24

```
=ABS($I$3-I4)=MIN(ABS($I$3-$I4:$I24))
```

*This is all being done through Google Sheets (not sure if this is relivant but thought it couldn't hurt being included)*

[image: Exact image of the conditional formatting from the sheet]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, let's change `$I4:$I24` to `$I$4:$I$24`, so that this array is the same for all cells that the formula is applied to.

The `-` operator only works for numbers, not arrays. So when you subtract an array from a number, it returns just the value minus the first number in the array. The same goes for the `ABS` function - it can't take an array.

To instead have the `-` operator and `ABS` function apply to each element of the array individually, you need to use the `ARRAYFORMULA` function. To do this, wrap the `ABS($I$3-$I$4:$I$24)` in `ARRAYFORMULA` - that is, `ARRAYFORMULA(ABS($I$3-$I$4:$I$24))`. Now, `ABS` and `-` apply to each element of the array individually, and return an array of all the results. This can then be passed into `MIN`.

Now we get

`=ABS($I$3-I4)=MIN(ARRAYFORMULA(ABS($I$3-$I$4:$I$24)))`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=ArrayFormula(ABS($I$3-I4)=MIN(ABS($I$3-$I$4:$I$24)))
```